# How to use Monochromatic icons in Action bar in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to use Monochromatic icons in Action bar in xamarin android. Currently, I have add normal png images using xml. Please help me to add these programmatically ? [image]

Comment: Also not able to change action bar text color using programmatically in xamarin android

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color of actionbar with following code:-

**ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor(["Your Color hex code"])));**